# Can't get gulp-less to run only if file has changed

Tags: gulp, gulp-less

I can't get gulp-less to not process everything, everytime. I've tried:

1. updating my version of gulp
2. using gulp-changed
3. using gulp-newer

It works with gulp-ngmin, but not with gulp-less

So this processes test.js only if I change test.js:

```
var SRC = 'test.js';
var DEST = 'dist';

gulp.task('test', function () {
    return gulp.src(SRC)
        .pipe(changed(DEST))
        // ngmin will only get the files that
        // changed since the last time it was run
        .pipe(ngmin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(DEST));
});
```

But everytime I run this task, it computes the less

What is wrong here?

```
var SRC = 'test.less';
var DEST = 'dist';

gulp.task('test', function () {
    return gulp.src(SRC)
        .pipe(changed(DEST))
        .pipe(less({
                paths: [path.join(__dirname, 'less', 'includes')]
            }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(DEST));
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually Nikita's statement is false, it does work and it is it's purpose, just make sure you are setting it up correctly. In my case I have this:

```
var gulp         = require('gulp');
var less         = require('gulp-less');
var changed      = require('gulp-changed');

gulp.task('less', function () 
{  
    gulp.src('./src/less/pages/*.less')
        .pipe(changed( 'outputDir/css', {extension: '.css'}))
        .pipe(less({
            paths: [ './src/less/' ]
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest( 'outputDir/css') );
});
```

My `gulp.src` points to the folder where I have my main LESS files (files which import other LESS files) and I want them all compiled into the destination folder.

In `.pipe(changed())` you must have the same target as you have in `.pipe(gulp.dest())`.

You can specify the extension to be compared to make it speedier (`{extension: '.css'}`) in `pipe(changed())`.

Perhaps you need to double check your `paths: [path.join(__dirname, 'less', 'includes')]`. In my case, I just placed there the root folder of all my less files. Some of my LESS files are in `src/less/globals` and others in `src/less/common`. The files I want to compile are in `src/less/pages`. So I used `src/less/pages/*.LESS` in `gulp.src()` and `src/less/` in less `pipe(less({paths: []}))`.

Comment: You mentioned 'globals' and 'common'. Will this automagically know to compile top level pages if imports have changed? Judging by the documentation it doesn't... but just in case you've found a way?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **gulp-less-changed** package, it will check the less file compilation hierarchy, considering the `@import`s used

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var lessChanged = require('gulp-less-changed');
var rename = require('rename');
var less = require('gulp-less');

var outputPat = "dest";

gulp.task('less', () => {
    return gulp.src('src/*.less')
        .pipe(lessChanged({
            getOutputFileName: file => rename(file, { dirname: outputPath, extname: '.css' })
        }))
        .pipe(less())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(outputPath));
});
```